# SOCKS connection fail with Node.js Request

Tags: node.js, proxy, request, socks

I'm trying to GET request a URL using a SOCKS connection to the [Private Internet Access proxy server](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/258/private-internet-access-proxy-now-available-now-open), but getting this error:
`Error: SOCKS connection failed. Connection not allowed by ruleset.` from the `socks5-http-client` npm package.

My code:

```
var request = require('request')
var Agent = require('socks5-http-client/lib/Agent')

var options = {
    url: url,
    agentClass: Agent,
    agentOptions: {
        socksHost: 'proxy-nl.privateinternetaccess.com', 
        socksPort: 1080,
        socksUsername: 'USERNAME',
        socksPassword: 'PASSWORD'
    }
}

request(options, function (error, res, html) {
  if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {

  }else {
    logging.error(error)
  }
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45196923/9271130 - this is right answer!

you must keep in mind that the problem may be on the server side, I often come across this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTTPS SOCKS connection was required (nothing in error message about this).

It worked to use this library instead: 
`socks5-https-client/lib/Agent`